# How to change font in ducksay bubble

Tags: fonts

How to change the font family in the ducksay bubble? I tried the `bubble=...` key as suggested in the documentation, but the font doesn't change.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ducksay}

\AddAnimal{test}
{
x
}

\begin{document}

\sffamily x
\ducksay[animal=test,bubble=\sffamily,body=\sffamily]{x}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `msg` is meant to set the text:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ducksay,xcolor}

\begin{document}

\ducksay[animal=duck,msg=\sffamily\color{red},
        body=\sffamily\color{green},bubble=\sffamily\color{blue}]
{some text}

\end{document}
```

[image]